# Codeigniter default_controller route

Tags: codeigniter, routes

In my codeigniter project all my routes are working fine, apart from the default_controller, which always returns a 404. Sample of my routes:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/$3'; // Region / language / page
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/index'; // Region / language

$route['default_controller'] = "home/region_select";
```

So when the user first visits the site, the idea is to go to the default_controller, where he selects a region. All the other routes work. In the "Home" controller I have a "region_select" function. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a file in `application/controller/home/region_select.php`? That's what is searches for now, and it looks like you want the default controller to load the function `region_select`, however this only fetches controller and loads `index()` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home/region_select/";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

and put the region_select function's content in to the index function of home controller and see what happens.

may be it will work.

please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Actually `home/region_select` is accepted. CI tries to load the function as well. take a look at `core/Route.php` class `line #310`

Comment: @Hashem Qolami you are right.but sometimes things not working if it is right.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have to apologise to everyone who answered for wasting their time. I discovered the issue was a conditional in my 'home' constructor, which took a URI segment and tested its validity, returning 404 if it was invalid. Of course, since the root has no URI segments, it returned invalid. I fixed it by checking for the presence of the URI segment before testing its validity. Thanks to everyone for their help.